C# LibraryImport string output parameter marshalling
I have a native function that will write a string to a buffer provided in the call along with its size. Let's call it GetFooString(LPStr str, int strLen).
I found out so far that with DllImport the following would work:
[DllImport("foo.dll", EntryPoint = "GetFooString")]
public static extern void GetFooString(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)]
    StringBuilder pBuff,
    ushort wBuffLen);

There is also this learn.microsoft.com which states that StringBuilder in P/Invoke should be avoided because of hidden allocations which can hurt performance. The workaround is to do the Marshalling manually by hand.
Since there is source generators based P/Invoke now I figured I can try and use that(compile time generated interop code should have better performance than what DllImport was doing). If I substitute DllImport with LibraryImport the error is that StringBuilder is not supported in source generated P/Invoke with the same MarshallAsAttribute as in the DllImport example. What is the correct way of calling such function with LibraryImport? Is there a way that would write to a stack allocated Span<char> which I can then convert to a string or do anything I could do with a Span?
Solution:
Based on Simon Mourier's answer I made a wrapper function around the P/Invoke that uses the span char buffer as a byte buffer in the P/Invoke and then converts the ANSI chars to UTF16. Unfortunately it seems Microsoft does not want to support the P/Invoke string out buffer scenario. Another solution could be to make a custom Marshaller for this case but I find them poorly documented and hard to work with which is why I went with the wrapper approach.
[LibraryImport("foo.dll", EntryPoint = "GetFooString")]
private static partial void GetFooStringImpl(
Span<byte> pBuff,
ushort wBuffLen);

public static void GetFooString(Span<char> pBuff)
{
    Span<byte> span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<char, byte>(pBuff)[(pBuff.Length - 1)..];
    GetFooStringImpl(span, (ushort)(pBuff.Length + 1));
    Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(span[..^1], pBuff);
}


https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/35862

Are you using .NET 8+?

@SimonMourier Yes, .NET 8. Will be upgrading to .NET 9 too.

@HansPassant It doesn't seem to work if ANSI/UTF8 need to be converted to UTF16 to work with in C#. It was my bad I wrote the unmanaged signature in the question as it would be in standard C. Not really used to Win32 API. The string to retrieve is actually an ANSI string.

There are many ways to do it. The "old" way works fine and is quite safe. About performance, it really depends on your context, we've been living with this for more than 20 years and it's not that bad.
If you need to be AOT compatible (with disabled runtime marshalling) then you'll have to abandon StringBuilder.
Now it looks you need Ansi/UTF8, and if you want or need to use LibraryImport, and since it requires the .NET project to be marked unsafe using AllowUnsafeBlocks, here is one unsafe solution:
internal partial class Program
{
    static unsafe void Main()
    {
        var bytes = stackalloc byte[10];
        GetFooString(bytes, 10);
        var s = Utf8StringMarshaller.ConvertToManaged(bytes); // .NET 7+
    }

    [LibraryImport("myDll")]
    public static unsafe partial void GetFooString(byte* str, int len);
}


My "performance context" is a hardware testing application. I am communicating with a LIN Network. In my case the less managed allocations that will be marked for cleanup immediately after use the better. A bad timed garbage collection could introduce latency in parts of the program where it really matters. I now I can suspend GC in critical parts but if I can limit allocations altogether it is better as well. Your unsafe solution was obvious. I hoped that there will be a way to avoid unsafe code in a quiet common case like ANSI/UTF8 to UTF16 conversion.

With LibraryImport you'll have to support unsafe anyway (but it's generated code). Also .NET uses UTF16 internally (as most of every Windows-originated piece of code), so it's expected to suffer Ansi/UTF8 conversions, unsafe or not, and it's not so "common" for a Windows developer. In my personal case, I always use UTF16 in my Windows C++ code for 25+ years for that reason

I have searched a little bit more for a better way but without any. It seems there is no direct support for the "out string" P/Invoke scenario. I ended up with a slight variation of your answer with Spans instead of pointers and clever use of the supplied char buffer.
